# WPF Button content with '&' not accepting

Tags: wpf, xaml, button

I am creating and with content 'Save & Add'. I write it in XAML, but the symbol '&' is not accepting. What is the reason for that. How can I do that?

Comment: XAML is valid XML and you can't use an & in XML without escaping it.

Answer (score 90, accepted):

Use **&amp;** instead of &.

You might find this article of some use - [How to: Use Special Characters in XAML](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/aa970677%28v=vs.100%29.aspx)

Comment: This link is not available!

Comment: e.g. Content="Terms &amp; Conditions"

Answer (score 28):

From [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Character_encodings_in_HTML#XML_character_entity_references):

> Unlike traditional HTML with its large range of character entity references, in XML there are only five predefined character entity references. These are used to escape characters that are markup sensitive in certain contexts:
>
> - &amp; → & (ampersand, U+0026)
> - &lt; → < (less-than sign, U+003C)
> - &gt; → > (greater-than sign, U+003E)
> - &quot; → " (quotation mark, U+0022)
> - &apos; → ' (apostrophe, U+0027)

Answer (score 5):

[image: How to: Use Special Characters in XAML]

Markup files that are created in Microsoft Visual Studio are automatically saved in the Unicode UTF-8 file format, which means that most special characters, such as accent marks, are encoded correctly

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa970677(v=vs.100).aspx

Answer (score 4):

You might need to escape it as "`&amp;`". See [this link](http://www.theukwebdesigncompany.com/articles/entity-escape-characters.php).